# Is there a way to interpret $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \frac{\ln(\omega^2+i\epsilon)}{\sqrt{\omega^2 + i \epsilon}}$

Tags: integration, distribution-theory, fourier-transform

I've been working on a problem in physics in which I've encountered the following Fourier transform:
$$
F(x) \equiv \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\omega\ \frac{\ln(\omega^2+i\epsilon)}{\sqrt{\omega^2 + i \epsilon}} e^{- i x \omega}
$$

I am wondering if there is any way to attach a meaning to the above function in terms of distributions?

My attempt: Since $\omega^2 > 0$, this means that $\lim\limits_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \ln( \omega^2 + i \epsilon ) = \ln(\omega^2)$ and I am tempted to use the [Sokhotski–Plemelj theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem) in the following (probably wrong) way:
$$
F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\omega \frac{\ln(\omega^2)}{|\omega|} e^{- i x \omega} - i \pi \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d\omega\ \delta(\omega)\ \ln(\omega^2) e^{- i x \omega}
$$

where I've [used the result of this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141036/dirac-delta-composed-with-absolute-value) to replace $\delta(|\omega|) \mapsto \delta(\omega)$.

I know that the Fourier transform of $\frac{\log|\omega|}{|\omega|}$ is $\left( \log|x| - \gamma \right)^2 + C$ for some constant $C$ (I'm not sure what $C$ is though). However, the second term in the above is obviously non-sense since I get $\ln(0)$ after performing the integral.

I know that you can't multiply distributions, so I'm not sure how to interpret the $\ln(\omega^2 + i \epsilon)$. I also know that I can't so simply take the limit $\epsilon \to 0^{+}$ in each of the functions separately...where am I wrong?

Or is this function just complete non-sense?

Comment: Don't forget the second term is a principal value.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fouriertransform%5B1%2F(w%5E2%2Ba%5E2)%5E(s),w,x%5D
differentiate w.r.t. $s$ and carefully analitically continiue to imaginary epislons in the end. Afterwards you can use known limiting formulas for the Bessel-K's

Comment: I think the way it's stated, this isn't going to work. You can define distributions induced by $f = \ln(\omega^2 + i \epsilon) / \sqrt {\omega^2 + i \epsilon}$, for any $\epsilon$. But if you apply them to a test function $\phi$ and try to find the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$, the limit doesn't exist (I believe there is a $\ln \epsilon / \sqrt \epsilon$ divergence). Therefore the limit in $F(x)$ doesn't exist either. I think what that means is that you should apply a regularization at some earlier step, defining the distribution to have a singular part, not just as the integral of $f \phi$.

Comment: @Maxim I have been looking through Kunwal at your recommendation. In Chapter 6, Equation (55) he gives the following relation:  $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \ln(x_{+}) e^{i u x} = i \frac{\frac{i\pi}{2} - \gamma}{u + i \epsilon} - \frac{\ln\left( u + i \epsilon \right)}{ u + i \epsilon }$$

Comment: Since $\frac{i}{u+i\epsilon} =i\mathrm{Pf}\left(\frac{1}{u}\right)+\pi\delta(u)$ is the FT of $H(x)$ (this is Eq (23)), working backwards I find that equation (55) implies a relation $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[ \left( \frac{i\pi}{2} - \gamma \right) H(x) - \ln(x_{+}) \right] e^{iux} dx = \frac{\ln(u+i\epsilon)}{u+i\epsilon}$, which then implies that: $$ \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln\left( u + i \epsilon \right)}{u+i \epsilon} e^{- i u x} du = \left( \frac{i\pi}{2} - \gamma \right) H(x) - \ln(x_{+})$$

Comment: This is very similar to my Fourier transform which looks like $\frac{\ln(u^2 + i \epsilon)}{\sqrt{u^2+i\epsilon}} \mapsto \frac{ 2 \ln(|u| + i \epsilon)}{|u|+i\epsilon}$. It seems so close but I am unsure how to adjust this relation to get the $|u|$ inside the function.

Comment: I stand by my previous claim. The sequence of the functionals $\ln(u + i \epsilon) / (u + i \epsilon)$ converges, and the limit of its Fourier transform or, which is the same thing, the Fourier transform of its limit is given by your last formula (you've lost $-i$ somewhere, the rhs should be multiplied by $-i$), while the sequence of your functionals $f_\epsilon(\omega)$ diverges.